# What is being translated as "hello dear", and why?

Tags: translation, machine-translation

It is fairly common on Stack Overflow for users to translate questions and/or responses into English using Google Translate.

One of the more amusing patterns I've noticed is when a translated answer begins "Hello Dear".  For example, these answers to technical questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688988/remove-selected-item-from-generic-list-via-a-button-and-listbox/17302146#17302146

> Hello dear use the simple code and solve your query...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20376046/2970321

> Hello dear you can search in an array fastly by using binaray search...

I'm pretty sure they don't mean "Hello dear" as the phrase would typically be used in American English (such as, by my grandmother).  Looking at the names of the posters, I would guess that the language being translated from is one spoken somewhere in South Asia, but that doesn't help me much.

My question is: which language(s), and which constructs in those languages are being (presumably) machine-translated in this odd manner, and why?

Comment: This really isn't a question about linguistics, it's a very specialized usage question about an insider culture.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid there's unlikely a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this often (in Europe), it is just a direct translation.  It is a peculiarity of Anglophone language or culture that it sounds so strange - and does indeed sound strange in English, being said from one anonymous man to another - as such an expression is common in many languages of Europe, Central Asia and South Asia, even relatively close cousins of English.

As it is so common, it is difficult to use this mistake to identify the speaker's native language.  It is likely even standard in South Asian English, at some level.

In German young men say *Mein Lieber* often to each other, in Romanian, Russian and some other related languages it is similar (either *my dear* or just *dear*, declined for gender).  In Turkey, Arabia, the Caucasus, Iran and Central Asia and South Asia, words like *habibi*, *aziz*, *can* (Turkish spelling) that can all be translated as *dear* are very common.

It is fine between men, even those who don't know each other, a bit like *brother*.

They say South Asia is a big place with many languages, so I can only speculate, but here is Wiktionary's no doubt incomplete list of cognates of the Persian word [جان](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%86#Persian), including Hindi and Urdu:

```
Tajik: ҷон ‎(jon)
→ Uzbek: jon
→ Azeri: can / جان / ҹан
→ Bashkir: йән ‎(yän)
→ Georgian: ჯანი ‎(ǯani)
→ Hindustani:
    Hindi: जान ‎(jān)
    Urdu: جان ‎(jān)
→ Kazakh: жан ‎(jan)
→ Kyrgyz: жан ‎(can)
→ Middle Armenian: ջան ‎(ǰan)
    Armenian: ջան ‎(ǰan)
→ Russian: джан ‎(džan)
→ Ottoman Turkish: جان
    Turkish: can
→ Albanian: xhan
→ Macedonian: џан ‎(džan)
→ Serbo-Croatian: džan / џан
→ Tatar: җан ‎(can)
→ Turkmen: jan
```

It's frankly relatively improbable that Hindi has Persian words that languages of Pakistan do not, so you can bet there are many more.  You can also be sure that there are other expressions with different origins.

Perhaps it used to be standard English.